# Error en fondo responsivo con Boostrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Tengo una página a la cual le puse un fondo con CSS, y la adapté para que se viera con ancho y largo de 100%. Al incluirle texto encima y verla en un celular, se descuadra.

Copio parte del código

**HTML**

```
<section id="banner">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="header-content col-md-8">
        <p style="font-size:225%">SOMOS LO QUE NECESITAS PARA TENER PRESCENCIA EN INTERNET</p>
        <hr width="100%">
        <p style="font-size:150%">El crecimiento de su negocio es nuestro principal objetivo!</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120%;
    position: center;
    background-image: url(../img/crecer.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    padding-top: 15%;
}
```

La imagen es de un tamaño 1366 x 800 px. Además, la imagen de fondo se mueve y hace que todo el contenido salga del área.

Comment: quiciera agregar que tambien la imagen de fondo se mueve y hace que todo el contenido salga del area... no se si a a alguien mas le pase

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y agregarlo a la pregunta? No me queda muy claro lo de "_la imagen de fondo se mueve y hace que todo el contenido salga del area_". La imagen de fondo no afecta al contenido ni a su posicionamiento.

Comment: la tengo en linea es www.seekingbusiness.com.mx/chris_orea
solamente se ve si lo ves desde un celular

Comment: @ChrisOrea ¿Te sirvio el código o tienes algun problema? :D

Comment: @hoose si, quedo excelente, el unico inconveniente es que mi fondo se mueve... la verdad no me habia pasado antes, es un problema que se origino un dia de la nada, la tengo en linea, se puede apreciar al verla desde un celular

Comment: @ChrisOrea ¿En qué sentido se mueve? ¿Podríamos verla en línea para ayudarte? :)

Comment: La tengo en www.seeingbusiness.com.mx/chris_orea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¡Hola!
Tu CSS #banner tiene un `width:120%` y un `position: center` que no existe en CSS.

```css
html, body{
    height:100%;
  }

#banner{
  background-image: url("http://mexicocarrental.mx/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/manzanillo-04.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

#banner p{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="banner">
      <div class="header-content col-md-8">
          <p>SOMOS LO QUE NECESITAS PARA TENER PRESENCIA EN INTERNET</p>
          <p>El crecimiento de su negocio es nuestro principal objetivo!</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Para poder hacer lo que deseas es necesario establecer en las etiquetas html y body un height del 100%. Y utilizar las siguientes propiedades de CSS, las cuales puedes leer [aquí](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp):

```
background-image: url("http://mexicocarrental.mx/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/manzanillo-04.jpg");
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: quedo perfecto 100%

Comment: @ChrisOrea Si te a ayudado, sería bueno que la pusieras como respuesta que resolvió tu problema, así podrías ayudar a demás usuarios que vengan a encontrarla de manera más rápida :)

Comment: es solo la mitad del problema amigo... aun tengo un fondo que me mueve todo... es algo molesto, pero nunca me había pasado, se ve únicamente en un móvil o tableta

Comment: @chris orea enseñanos el código :)

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la clase `col-sm`,agrega esto al head,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Utiliza la clase `img-responsive`

Prueba de esta manera , no se si es lo que quieres

html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="banner">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="header-content col-md-8">
                <p style="font-size:225%">SOMOS LO QUE NECESITAS PARA TENER PRESCENCIA EN INTERNET</p>
                <hr width="100%">
                <p style="font-size:150%">El crecimiento de su negocio es nuestro principal objetivo!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: center;
    background-image: url(crecer.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    padding-top: 15%;
}
```

Comment: tengo puesto en el codigo eso, y sobre la clase... no se si lo pueda agregar ya que mande a llamar el fondo por medio de CSS

Comment: Actualize mi respuesta , prueba asi entendi yo , @ChrisOrea

Comment: gracias ocupe parte de tu codigo y el de @hoose, quedo excelente