# Acomodar imagen de fondo al ancho de la página

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Quiero cambiar el tamaño de la imagen de fondo para acomodarla al ancho de la página pero no sé si es posible. Éste es mi código:

```css
#cabecera {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url('https://placehold.it/1000x400') no-repeat 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="cabecera">
  <div class="contenedor">
    <h1>Profesionales en tecnología de Desarrollo Web</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet unde perferendis repudiandae.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

¿Cómo cambio el tamaño para que ocupe todo el ancho de la página una imagen como background?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con `background-size: cover`

Comment: Esta pregunta puede tener respuesta en otras publicaciones del sitio: [Background imagen fondo HTML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/125496/250), [¿Cómo puedo poner una imagen de fondo tamaño completo en un div usando una URL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/7898/250), [Redimensionar imagen en CSS3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/96065/250) o [Fondo responsivo con boostrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/20540/250).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te aconsejo separar la propiedad acortada background, que actualmente tienes así:

```
background: url('https://placehold.it/1000x400') no-repeat 0;
```

Y puedes dividirla de esta manera:

```
background-image: url('https://placehold.it/1000x400');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*Centramos el fondo al centro*/
background-position: center;
/*Y le decimos que siempre ocupe el ancho y el alto con esto*/
background-size: cover;
```

Y listo:

```css
#cabecera {
  min-height: 400px;text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  
  background-image: url('https://placehold.it/1000x400');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section id="cabecera">
  <div class="contenedor">
    <h1>Profesionales en tecnología de Desarrollo Web</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet unde perferendis repudiandae.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola me imagino que esa imagen de #cabecera es un banner de 1000x400 tu imagen debe estar ajustada al tamaño de tu ancho de contenedor para que se pueda apreciar bien y no tenga perdidas al momento de visualizar la página

Comment: Realmente esto no responde a la pregunta. La idea es que en un sistema que se adapte a diferentes resoluciones, la imagen no siempre va a tener el tamaño del contenedor. El banner es de 1000x400 porque yo le puse ese tamaño al azar como ejemplo.

Answer (score -1):

Puede ser que solo te hacía falta hacer más ancha la imagen con un `witdh`, ya si le quieres dar más diseño a la imagen para acomodarla puedes jugar con los `margin-padding` :

```css
#cabecera {
    min-height: 400px;
    //Sólo pon esto
     width:100%;
   
    background: url('../img/HSTS-cabecera.jpg') no-repeat 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    
}
```

```html
<section id="cabecera">
        <div class="contenedor">
            <h1>Profesionales en tecnología de Desarrollo Web</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet unde perferendis repudiandae.</p>
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. El usuario quiere ajustar la imagen de fondo al ancho total, con esta solución se le está diciendo a la `#cabecera` que ocupe todo el ancho, pero la imagen de fondo de `#cabecera` no tendría por qué ocuparlo.